# Problems with the instalation of ROS INDIGO in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: rosinstall, ubuntu, ubuntu-trusty, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problems with installation of ROS INDIGO

When try to install ROS INDIGO get this error:

```
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
No se pudieron instalar algunos paquetes. Esto puede significar que
usted pidió una situación imposible o, si está usando la distribución
inestable, que algunos paquetes necesarios no han sido creados o han
sido movidos fuera de Incoming.
La siguiente información puede ayudar a resolver la situación:

Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
ros-indigo-desktop-full : Depende: ros-indigo-simulators pero no va a instalarse
E: No se pudieron corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos.
```

A lot fo thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188267/problems-with-the-instalation-of-ros-indigo-in-ubuntu-14.04/) by [vncntmh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4870/vncntmh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2014-07-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Long Hoang](https://answers.ros.org/users/19849/long-hoang/) on 2014-07-30**:
What Linux Distribution are you using?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-30**:
Do you have the universe and multiverse repositories enabled? Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4870/vncntmh/) on 2014-07-30**:
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04LTS and I'm not sure aboutn universe and multieverse

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-30**:
You should make sure that the universe and multiverse repositories are enabled, as explained in the Ubuntu Repositories guide that is linked from the Indigo installation page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu .

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4870/vncntmh/) on 2014-07-30**:
I have to select a server different that Main Server?

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4870/vncntmh/) on 2014-07-30**:
I configure Ubuntu repositories to allow "restricted," "universe," and "multiverse." but have the same problem

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-30**:
Have you run `sudo apt-get update` after adding the universe and multiverse repositories?

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4870/vncntmh/) on 2014-07-30**:
Yes, I did it! But continue tha same problem.... Before to try to install ROS INDIGO I installed Gazebo, maybe is this the problem?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-31**:
Which version of gazebo did you install? ROS Indigo is only compatible with gazebo 2.

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4870/vncntmh/) on 2014-07-31**:
I'm using Gazebo4, because it's only compatible with Ubuntu 14.04, but I don't know how do for work in Gazebo with ROS

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-31**:
I don't think they've released gazebo4 yet. Perhaps you're using gazebo3? In either case, you should probably uninstall gazebo, and allow ROS to install a version of gazebo that is compatible with ROS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem seems to be that the package *ros-indigo-simulators* collides with something that is already installed in your system and you end up with broken packages.

Try the following command:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

(The -f stands for "fix broken) and try again.

If it keeps happening, then you should uninstall whatever is colliding with *ros-indigo-simulators* (probably the previous installation of Gazebo that you mention in the comments of your question).

I hope it helps

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2014-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2